# Cached shadow path for UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to cache a shadow path to make the performance of `UITableView` better.

I've read https://yalantis.com/blog/mastering-uikit-performance/ that

```swift
if let rect = cell.imageView?.bounds {
    cell.imageView?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
}
```

would stop offscreen shadows, however using the following function

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell data: \(data[indexPath.row])"
        
        if let rect = cell.imageView?.bounds {
          cell.imageView?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
        }
        
        cell.imageView?.layer.shadowRadius = 8
        cell.imageView?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 3)
        cell.imageView?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        
        
        cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage")
        return cell
    }
```

produces a result where some cells have the shadow and some don't.

[image]

How can I implement caching of shadow paths to all cells in a simple `UITableView`

Comment: Could you confirm that your cell.imageView?.bounds are not nil

Comment: never nil, for those without the shadow Optional((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)), with Optional((0.0, 0.0, 44.0, 44.0))

Comment: You could keep a variable if once you get a UIBezierPath value you could store it and reuse it. You don't have to calculate it for every cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these lines:

```
    if let rect = cell.imageView?.bounds {
        cell.imageView?.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
    }
```

If the cell's `imageView` has never been assigned an image, its `frame` is `.zero` and so its `bounds` is `.zero`. So the `shadowPath` ends up with a `cgPath` that is just a point, and no shadow appears.

The way I would solve this is that I would not use the built-in `imageView` property at all. I'd use a custom cell class with my own image view whose frame I can control, instead of the built-in `imageView` which plays these sorts of tricks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let shadowPath = self.shadowPathCache {
    cell.imageView?.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath
} else if let rect = cell.imageView?.bounds { 
    self.shadowPathCache = UIBezierPath(rect: rect).cgPath
    cell.imageView?.layer.shadowPath = self.shadowPathCache
}
```